# GraphicsMagick montage 2x1 with an odd number

Tags: pdf, imagemagick, ghostscript, graphicsmagick

I'm using this command to merge PDFs 2x1

```
gm montage -mode concatenate -rotate 90 -tile 2x1 ${labels.join(" ")} ${out}
```

The problem, is if there are 5 PDFs, then the 1 is in the center. Is there anyway to get this where the last one, or an uneven one is left aligned, and not center aligned?

The result right now

Page 1

```
|     ||      |
|     ||      |
|     ||      |
```

Page 2

```
   |      |
   |      |
   |      |
```

The desired result for page 2

```
|     |
|     |
|     |
```

Thanks!

Comment: Try the "-gravity west" option.  You can put it right before the "-mode concatenate" option.  The single one might also get scaled larger than the others, to fit the page.  Use -geometry WxH to set the tile sizes to the same width and height.

Comment: What size would I use for WxH if I just want it to be half the size of a sheet of paper? Should I figure out it in inches at 72dpi and convert to pixels?

Comment: Assuming A3 paper which is the default for GraphicsMagick (portrait, 842x1190), use "-geometry 421x595".  If you specify the geometry this way you won't need the "-gravity west" option because the image already fits the tile exactly.

Comment: So I tried that, both with size and gravity west. The issue is that it doesn't create white-space on the right. So the image is still centered.  I think we need gravity west with some white-space option to fill in the extra space. Or I could just create a blank white PDF and merge that in to make it even.

Comment: "gm montage -gravity center -geometry 792x306 -mode concatenate -rotate 90 tile 2x1 input.pdf output.pdf", where input.pdf contains three images, works for me to write a US letter sized page.  I'm using GraphicsMagick 1.3.18 and ImageMagick-6.8.8-7.  GM puts the images at the bottom of the page while IM centers them vertically.

Comment: So the only thing I've got working (finally) Was to detect an odd number of images, add one more that is a white PDF of the right size.  I could probably generate that PDF on the fly but who cares.

So for now, the answer is, force it to be even by adding one more image.

Answer (score 0):

So far the only thing i've found to work is to detect if there are an odd number of images, if so, add one more image the same size as the others.  The "one more" is just a blank white image.